# Is there a way for me to have the data from my accelerometer automatically added to a sqlite database?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, accelerometer, android-sensors

I have created a accelerometer for my application, I wanted to know is there a way to have the data from the axis automatically added to a sqlite database? Or would I have to manually add the figures in myself?

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

There's no api to achieve that. You'd have to do that manually:

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    acclX = event.values[0];
    acclY =event.values[1];
    acclZ = event.values[2];

         insertReadings(acclX, acclY, acclZ); // YOUR method to insert to sqlite DB.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use [ormlite](http://ormlite.com/). It's simple way to working with database. Minor(not completly) example:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "accel")
public class AccelerometerRec {

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    int id;
    @DatabaseField
    int x;
    @DatabaseField
    int y;
    @DatabaseField
    int z;
}
```

How save?

```
accelDao = DaoManager.createDao(connectionSource, AccelerometerRec.class);
accelDao.create(new AccelerometerRec(...))
```

See completly examples on official site.